# Why is .NET changing UTC date to server timezone?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, date, datetime

I have an AngularJS app that is posting a date in UTC format to a .NET controller:

```
CreateEvent: function (event) {

        var event_date = moment.utc(new Date(event.event_date)).format();

        return $http({
            url: '/test/CreateEvent/',
            method: "POST",
            data: { event_date: event_date}
        });

    }
```

If I put the date July 4 2016, 08:00 in event.event_date, moment converts that to "2016-07-03T22:00:00Z" which is posted to the server.

Below is a snippet of my .Net controller:

```
public JsonResult CreateEvent(@event evt, int eventOffset)
    {

        DateTime eventDate = evt.event_date;

        ...
    }
```

I've set a breakpoint on the first line and the evt.event_date contains the date July 4 2016, 08:00. My server is running in a GMT+10 timezone. Why is the date being converted to the current timezone and how do I stop this?

Comment: `evt.event_date.ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: Perfect thanks! But why, when I do a retrieve from the database, is the date not converted to GMT+10? I thought javascript automatically converted dates to the current timezone?

Comment: Depends how you store/load the information from the database - how is that related to javascript? Also, you're using the `moment` library, which behaves differently from the built-in javascript date handling.

Comment: You should leave code alone.  A computer stores data internally as a number in UTC.  Inputs and output are automatically convert from the local TimeZone settings to UTC in Net Library.  12:00PM EST (-5) is stored as 5:00PM UTC.  If data is collect in California at 12:00PM (-8) and entered in a computer in NYC is would incorrectly be entered as 5:00PM UTC.  With TimeZone setting correction it would be entered as 2:00PM UTC.  Data should always be entered with timezone setting where data was collected.  If data is collected in same timezone and PC setting timezone is not required.

Comment: A computer database driver transfers data to remote databases in utc time so if a computer and database are in different timezones the data get entered in database at time data was collected in utc.

Comment: In my case I tried to convert time to universal time as @Rob suggest but it didn't work. Then I tried in intermediate window what different ToSOmething() methods return and I noticed that ToLocalTIme() work in my case. I am not sure that is it good way but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a good short cut is to convert the date time to string with a definite format. The server side must remember the definite format.

I understand your problem. The JSON object's date property simply get converted irregardless the database and how you store, you don't even reach the point of storing in database. It must has something to do with serialization problems.

This is a good post for dates:-
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx